# Что за расширение Ubuntu Modifications для Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Чем занимается расширение Ubuntu Modifications для браузера Firefox, которое устанавливается вместе с OC?

В списке расширений оно не имеет сколь нибудь внятного описания. Это очередные шпионские штучки от космонавта?

Comment: ассоциация: https://askubuntu.com/q/226

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несмотря на столь таинственный облик, это довольно полезное дополнение к браузеру и ничем предосудительным оно не занимается. Судя по описанию пакета **xul-ext-ubufox**, который содержит данное расширение, оно делает следующее:

- Для ветки devel добавляет в меню «Справка» пункт «Сообщить о проблеме...»,
- Устанавливает по умолчанию в качестве домашней страницы начальную от Ubuntu,
- Отображает уведомления о необходимости перезапуска после обновления браузера.

[image: Снимок уведомления о необходимости перезапуска браузера]
<sup>Пример подобного уведомления в браузере Firefox</sup>